# Targeting XAML controls in C#

Tags: c#, xaml

I am a newbie to Visual Studio and its languages...

I have search but couldn't find an answer. Maybe I didn't search with the right syntax.

Here is what I want to do.

```
<TextBlock x:Name="test">Hello World</TextBlock>
```

I believe there is a way to target the TEXTBLOCK control with the X:NAME attribute or any other attribute using C# like for example in HTML and JS I can do something like this

```
<div id="test></div>
```

Then I can target the Element through its ID in JS like this

```
div = document.getElementById('test');
```

I believe I can do similar in C#

Please any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**XAML**

```
<TextBlock x:Name="TestTextBlock">Hello World</TextBlock>
```

**CodeBehind**

```
TestTextBlock.Text = "blerg";
```

Though on saying this, XAML Likes to be data bound, and the common way of doing this is using MVVM, i would start looking into this personally